# Prestashop default theme customizing method

Tags: php, customization, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am a newbie in Prestashop, but I already worked with CMS during my professional experience.

I don't understand why in each file in the defalut theme, there is a disclaimer asking to do not edit the file if I want to update Prestashop to newer versions.

Does it mean that the default theme is also updated during Prestashop update? In my opinion, it goes against the purpose of the  3-tier architecture

What should I edit so that I can customize the default theme as I like? Can someone point me to a link where I can find the best practices regarding theme development?
Thanks

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on http://www.daveegerton.com/prestashop-guides/Prestashop-Designers-Guide/Themes/modifying-the-default-prestashop-theme.html ...btw it, too, suggests to duplicate the default theme if you want to edit it.

Comment: @jave.web thank you for the link, useful for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the official docs](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+your+own+theme):

> The first step is plain in simple: make a straight copy of PrestaShop's default theme folder.

So you first make a copy with a new folder name, and then make all the edits you need in that copy. You can enable your new theme from the backend in Preferences -> Themes. I had to reload the page twice for being able to enable my theme.

In the linked doc you'll find more tips. It is for Prestashop 1.5, the Designer Guide for 1.6 is not out yet, but the idea is the same.

Comment: 1.6 Guide is ready I think - reffer to **Standing on the shoulders of giants: copying the default theme** - chapter on this page: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Laying+the+Theme%27s+Foundations

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of the default template folder, rename it and then you can modify whatever you want without worrying about the updates.